# Префикс перед string: '$'

Tags: c#, c#-faq

Прошерстил весь свой справочник по C# и не смог найти что такое '$'.

Я понял только то, что это чем-то похоже на verbatim string '@'.

```
Console.WriteLine($"?");
```

Как это влияет на строку?

Comment: [Interpotaled String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) - Добавлено в c#6

Comment: @grundy
Спасибо

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Префикс `$` перед строкой обозначает, что далее идет интерполированная строка.

Интерполяция используется для удобного конструирования строки. При этом выражение интерполированных строк может выглядеть как шаблон строки, в котором могут быть использованы выражения языка.

Интерполированные строки легче в понимании относительно аргументов, по сравнению с [композитным форматированием](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)

Пример:

```
var s = $"Name = {name}, hours = {hours:hh}";
```

По сравнению с [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var s = string.Format("Name = {0}, hours = {1:hh}", name, hours);
```

**Важное отличие** от того же [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx):

> [String interpolation is transformed at compile time to invoke an equivalent string.Format call. This leaves in place support for localization as before (though still with traditional format strings) and doesn’t introduce any post compile injection of code via strings.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dn879355.aspx)

> Интерполированная строка в момент компиляции трансформируется в эквивалентный вызов [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx). Это оставляет поддержку локализации как прежде (хотя все еще с традиционным форматированием строк) и не позволяет добавлять любые инъекции кода в строку, после компиляции.

Данная возможность появилась с выходом [C# 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dn879355.aspx).

Подробнее можно почитать в [справке на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)

Comment: А `String.Format` - это спецификация говорит, или просто деталь реализации?

Comment: @Qwertiy, это в статье так написано, в спецификации не смотрел, что к чему

Answer (score 3):

Это интерполяция строк, удобная вещь, которая позволяет написать выражение:

```
int i=1;
Console.WriteLine($"i={i}");
```

Подробнее тут:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn961160.aspx

Comment: по-русски: замена `string.Format()` появившаяся в C# 6

Comment: @tCode, не замена

Comment: @tcode
Похоже я отстал от жизни со справочник по C# 4.0...

Comment: @tCode Разница с string.Format в том, что паттерн резолвится во время компиляции (литералом), а в Format его можно подсовывать динамически.

Comment: ладно ладно))))

Comment: Ну это важный момент, таким образом интерполированная строка быстрее формирует строку, но не позволяет в рантайме использовать другой шаблон вывода.

Comment: @Grundy для большинства способов применения - таки замена. Ну да, неполная замена получается. Но замена же!

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ещё вот так нельзя: `"{0} smth {0}"`.

Comment: @Qwertiy это кто вам сказал?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а как ты хочешь это в интерполируемой строке сделать? Компилятор не может же подстановки объединять.