# Visual Studio 2015 форматирование строк

Tags: visual-studio

Пишу код в visual studio 2015. И нужно создать строку проинициализировав ее некоторым текстом.

Например

> Arrange all necessary preconditions and inputs.
>
> Act on the object or method under test.
>
> Assert that the expected results have occurred.

Вотпрос в том, что для этого мне надо сделать переносы строк в коде(чтобы помещалось на экран) и экранировать символы в случае необходимости. В Android Studio при вставке строки в код автоматически экранируются символы, а при переносе строки а автоматически сплитит строку по правилу "строка"+"продолжение". Есть ли что-то похожее в студии? Или это все делать вручную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для с# в таких случаях используется `@"строка"` Но экранировать нужно двойную кавычку двумя двойными (`""` вместо `"`).

```
string s = @"Ваш код с \ символами ";
```

Ещё для "" есть префикс $"" [Префикс перед string: '$'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603372/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-string/603390) используется именно для форматирования (замены string.Format)

Так же при использовании @ допускается так (такой перенос сам добавляет \n):

```
   string s=@"строка 1
строка 2";
```

Comment: Я поправил ответ. Перенос = "<enter>".

Comment: А двойные кавычки в строке значит тольку руками экранировать?

Comment: К сожалению да, это можно сделать любым редактором `Поиск-Замена` или search-replace.

Comment: Ну так мы умеем, да:) Спасибо! Ответ полный и хорошо оформленный